# JavaFX Task, Service - Exception

Tags: multithreading, background, javafx

I don't know why, but I'm getting exception like that on JavaFX application.

Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5

In another task, which is in Service I'm trying to load a file, or to connect to a database. These are time-consuming operations so I want to perform them in background but I can't...
That task is started after pressing a button.

I read that you get it when you try to update gui in another thead Task, but I dont do this here.

```
try{
            webEngine.load("http://www.analiza.host-ed.me/wynik.html");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Blad: "+e); //I get the exception from there
            }
```

I tried also: webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("wynik.html").toExternalForm());
and got the same

Thanks for answers.

Comment: "exception like that"? Exception like *what*? You haven't told us what exception you're getting. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list (And what does this have to do with the TPL, which is .NET?)

Comment: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5

Comment: That doesn't even tell us what the exception type is, let alone a full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `webEngine.load` call in [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

See [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) to understand in detail how to do this and why it is necessary.